# Regexp - only complete words and not after a specific character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find complete words in a string, but I'm having trouble where the word occurs after hyphen.
How do I create the regex to ignore the words that occur after hyphen?

```
var text = "google e-google alphagooglebeta google google";
var word = "google";
var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + word + "\\b", "g");
var result = text.replace(regex, "SUCCESS");

output: "SUCCESS e-SUCCESS alphagooglebeta SUCCESS SUCCESS"
expected output: "SUCCESS e-google alphagooglebeta SUCCESS SUCCESS"
```

Comment: I tried several things, but without success

Comment: `var regex = new RegExp("(^|\\s)(" + word + ")(?!\\S)", "g");`, replace with `$1SUCCESS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```js
var text = "google e-google alphagooglebeta google google";
var word = "google";
var regex = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + word + "(?=\\s|$)", "g");
var result = text.replace(regex, "$1SUCCESS");

console.log(result);
//=> SUCCESS e-google alphagooglebeta SUCCESS SUCCESS
```

Regex `/(^|\s)google(?=\s|$)/` matches `google` if it is preceded by start or whitespace. We capture this part in a capturing group.

`(?=\s|$)` is zero-width lookahead assertion that asserts that we have a whitespace or line end ahead.